# Unable to select element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I am trying to select an element with selenium and I am unable to select it. I tried selecting it with xpath, css, and executing javascript to click it but no luck. Any ideas?

I was able to select it using katalon ide automation plugin and within the javascript console which leads me to believe that there is a way to do it.

Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark").click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(1)
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.rc-audiochallenge-tdownload-link")))
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.rc-audiochallenge-tdownload-link").click()
```

I am trying to select the audio button here:[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify which element can't find

Comment: Show related HTML code,  I tried there is no such element: `a.rc-audiochallenge-tdownload-link`

Comment: Have you tried this id? recaptcha-audio-button

Answer (score 2):

There is no such element locator with `a.rc-audiochallenge-tdownload-link`, There is id `recaptcha-audio-button` present on audio button... Try Id selector..e.g.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID, "recaptcha-audio-button"))
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "recaptcha-audio-button").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how did you write down such locator: `a.rc-audiochallenge-tdownload-link` , There is no such element in the whole page. Is the web page changed later?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To click the `#recaptcha-audio-button`, you can use (tested):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark").click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@title='recaptcha challenge']"))
driver.find_element(By.ID, "recaptcha-audio-button").click()
```